# Modified Django admin clean() method not being invoked

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have developed a tool (to be used internally) based on the Django admin site.

I have model validators in place which work brilliantly, but to do more complex validations, I am attempting to overwrite the clean() method in admin.py

My admin.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Provider, Employer, Person, Learnership, Qualification, Unit_Standard
from django import forms
```

class ProviderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Provider
        fields = '**all**'

```
    def clean(self):
        provider_start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('provider_start_date')
        provider_end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('provider_end_date')
        if provider_start_date > provider_end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Start date can't be after end date")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

admin.site.register(Provider)

The models.py for the Provider Model:

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    ... lots of stuff here ...
    provider_start_date = models.DateField()
    provider_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ... lots of stuff here ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.provider_name, self.provider_code)
```

The problem is that the code displayed in the admin.py doesn't seem to fire, and you can save the record with the end date before the start date.

The Django admin interface is really an amazing feature of the framework, and I think that other people have probably also run into this problem of more advanced validations not being possible, so it would help them as well.

Comment: Please fix indentation

Comment: Note that it should be `fields = '__all__'`, not `'all'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created a model form, but you have not told Django to use it.

You should create a model admin, and set [`form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) to your model form:

```
class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProviderForm
```

Then register your model with your model admin class:

```
admin.site.register(Provider, ProviderAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call the super() int the clean method:

```
def clean(self):

    cleaned_data = super(ProviderForm, self).clean()
```

EDIT:

This is not the correct answer, @Alasdair above is. As pointed by @scharette in the comments

> This is relevant only if your form inherits another that doesn’t
>   return a cleaned_data dictionary in its clean() method. Also, if
>   you're using python 3 there is no need to have parameters

Comment: This is relevant only if your form inherits another that doesn’t return a cleaned_data dictionary in its `clean()` method. Also, if you're using python 3 there is no need to have parameters.

Comment: you should definately edit your answer, by referencing to Alasdair's answer and add my clarifiaction, because it is a good point, only wrongly stated.

Comment: Nice insight btw.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your indentation is only an issue of posting your code, my guess is you forgot to override the admin class. Here is what you need to do:

```
class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProviderForm


admin.site.register(Provider,ProviderAdmin)
```

You were on the right path you just forgot to register an override on the admin class by specifying the form with `clean` override

Comment: Thanks so much, it works - I don't really know the protocol for StackOverflow, but I guessed that I needed to mark the first answer correct, even though you were both correct?

Comment: You can mark whichever answer you want as correct, [it doesn't need to be the first one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262284/what-answer-should-i-accept-faster-vs-more-documented).

Comment: You did the right thing by accepting his since it was the exact samething and he was first. glad it helped!! thanks to @Alasdair +1