# Django admin interface FormAdmin not registering second Form override

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I had an issue a while back with a [clean() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056158/modified-django-admin-clean-method-not-being-invoked), which is now working. But when I added a second Form into the mix, no code from that clean() method seems to fire at all.

I tried copying the previous one that does work down to the last detail, but only the first one works.

**Here is the code:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Provider, Employer, Person, Learnership, Qualification,    Unit_Standard, Alternate_Id_Type_Id
from django import forms

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):

        person_alternate_id = self.cleaned_data.get('person_alternate_id')
        alternate_id_type_id = self.cleaned_data.get('alternate_id_type_id')        

        if person_alternate_id is not None and alternate_id_type_id == 533:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Type ID")
        if person_alternate_id is None and alternate_id_type_id != 533:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Type ID")
        ...
        return self.cleaned_data

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PersonForm

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

**For reference, this one still works perfectly:**

```
class ProviderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Provider
        fields = '__all__'


    def clean(self):

        provider_start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('provider_start_date')
        provider_end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('provider_end_date')
        if provider_start_date > provider_end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Start date can't be after end date")
        ....
        return self.cleaned_data

class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProviderForm

admin.site.register(Provider, ProviderAdmin)
```

There don't appear to be any error messages at all, so I'm not sure how to debug it - there is just no response at all. When I save a record that should be caught by the above exceptions (in the Person form), it just saves no matter what I do.

Comment: just to be sure: your call to `return self.cleaned_data` is indented correctly? In the snippet above it's not.

Comment: Thanks for that - I fixed it in the snippet (but yes, it is correct in the actual code) :)